# error message: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2014

I searched SO but have not found a solution to my error.
I am using VS 2013, and SQL Server 2014.

Below is my connectionstring:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("cnInvestTracker"))
{

}
```

My web.config is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="cnInvestTracker" 
          connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=InvestTracker;Integrated Security=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am getting an error message when the code executes the using line. The error message is:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0.

What is causing the error?

Comment: you can't access the webConfig I will post a fix for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value `"cnInvestTracker"` *itself* isn't a valid connection string.  Which is what you're trying to use here:

```
new SqlConnection("cnInvestTracker")
```

That constructor doesn't want the *name* of a connection string, it wants [the connection string itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7469at0.aspx):

```
new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnInvestTracker"].ConnectionString)
```

(You may have to add a reference to `System.Configuration`, and you may want to add some error checking to make sure a connection string of that name exists before trying to reference it.)

Comment: That did it. Thanks @David. Will accept answer in 7 minutes

Answer (score 2):

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnInvestTracker"].ConnectionString))
{

}
```

you will probably want to do more with the code once you establish a connection so below is an example of what you can do if you are wanting to return data for example into a DataTable using the `.Fill()`

```
SqlDataAdapter sda;
DataTable someDataTable = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnInvestTracker"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ups_GeMyStoredProc", connStr)) //replace with your stored procedure. or Sql Command 
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(someDataTable);
    }
}
```