# Weird error while using SqlConnection and AttachDbFilename

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

I'm facing a weird error while trying to connect to an attached DB in my web app.

My connection string:

```
<add name="ExtJSTestDB" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\KODatatableContext.mdf;User Instance=True;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The code in controller:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection("ExtJSTestDB")){...}
```

Right at the moment of call "new SqlConnection" I get this:

Exception thrown:

> 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Das Format der Initialisierungszeichenfolge stimmt nicht mit der Spezifikation überein, die bei Index '0' beginnt.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a language tag and a tag for the database you try to connect to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error message: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787143/error-message-format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-specifica) (same problem and exception but with the error message in English).

Answer (score 2):

If your connectionString in `Web.config`  xml element connectionStrings`

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ExtJSTestDB" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\KODatatableContext.mdf;User Instance=True;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

You can't use  `name="ExtJSTestDB"` to set connection string,You need to use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` Concollection  to read ConnectionString data.

```
string connStr= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExtJSTestDB"];
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connStr)){...}
```